# Using \begin{TeXtoEPS} after \section

Tags: pstricks

I have a figure created with `pstricks` that I would like to insert
into another document. However when copying the markup into my main document
and compiling it I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError ...
\#4 \errhelp \@err@ ...
l.21 \end{TeXtoEPS}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The error occurs if there is a `\section` before `\begin{TeXtoEPS}`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,dvips]{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}   
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\begin{document}0
\pagestyle{empty}

% The following line causes the issue
\section{Introduction}
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\psset{unit=0.7}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(20,10)
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=black,linestyle=solid}
\psline{->}(0,8)(10,8)
\psline{->}(0,0)(10,0)

\end{pspicture}

\end{TeXtoEPS}

\end{document}
```

How would one use the TeXtoEPS environment inside a section?
I was intending to just wrap the figures inside my main document with the `\begin{TeXtoEps}`. Am I going about this the wrong way?

EDIT:

Thanks to Urike's comment which pointed me in the right direction:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvi]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}   
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{Introduction}
\psset{unit=0.7}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(20,10)
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=black,linestyle=solid}
\psline{->}(0,8)(10,8)
\psline{->}(0,0)(10,0)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And compiled with `latex->dvips -> psdpdf`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Don't use the package pst-eps and the TeXtoEPS: It clashes with the newer `auto-pst-pdf` loaded by pstricks (that's what the option `pdf` does).  Remove both. Remove also the `dvips` option in the header and then compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, your comment pointed me in the right direction (see edit), I'll mark it as the answer if you post it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the package `pst-eps` and the environment `TeXtoEPS`: It clashes with the newer `auto-pst-pdf` loaded by `pstricks` (that's what the option `pdf` does). Remove both. Remove also the `dvips` option in the header and then compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape`